# search array with multitext value

Tags: php, arrays, search, foreach, multitexturing

in this array, I want to find word "in" from value and make new array from that songs including number (key) songs from album.

```
$londonCalling = array(
'song-01' => 'London Calling',
'song-02' => 'Brand New Cadillac',
'song-03' => 'Jimmy Jazz',
'song-04' => 'Hateful',
'song-05' => 'Rudie Cant Fail',
'song-06' => 'Spanish Bombs',
'song-07' => 'The Right Profile',
'song-08' => 'Lost in the Supermarket',
'song-09' => 'Clampdown',
'song-10' => 'The Guns of Brixton',
'song-11' => 'Wrong Em Boyo',
'song-12' => 'Death or Glory',
'song-13' => 'Koka Kola',
'song-14' => 'The Card Cheat',
'song-15' => 'Lovers Rock',
'song-16' => 'Four Horsemen',
'song-17' => 'Im Not Down',
'song-18' => 'Revolution Rock',
'song-19' => 'Train in Vain');
```

Comment: try simple foreach loop

Comment: a PHP tutorial comes in handy in situations like these

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) oneliner:

```
print_r(preg_grep('/in/', $londonCalling));
```

Comment: `preg_grep` is the correct choice. Finding "the word" would be `/\bin\b/` (word boundary)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively array_filter

```
$res = array_filter($londonCalling , function($e){
    return strpos($e, 'in') !== false;
});

print_r([$res]);
```